# How to reclaim free space partition on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, diskutil

I was trying to expand my main drive by deleting a third partition I used to have after deleting and formatting with free space:

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume "Free Space" %noformat% /dev/disk0s2
```

I could not expand my drive and now I can't find the drive I formatted "free space"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To convert an APFS container to free space you'd have to delete the container first:

```
diskutil ap deleteContainer disk1
```

Then you can demote the partition to unallocated disk space with:

```
diskutil eraseVolume "Free Space" %noformat% /dev/disk0s2
```

---

You won't be able to reclaim more disk space for your remaining container disk2 (disk0s3) though, because you can't expand disk0s3 to lower block numbers.

As of today you can't move APFS volumes between APFS containers.

Your options are then:

1. Reboot to Internet Recovery Mode

   - create a partition `disk0s2` in the unallocated disk space with gpt. The partition has to have the same size and type as disk0s3.
   - unmount all container `disk2` volumes
   - `dd` `disk0s3` to `disk0s2`
   - delete Container `disk2`
   - expand the remaining container
2. Install High Sierra to container `disk1` (the container `disk1` mustn't be erased as described in the first part then) and import data from container `disk2`.

   - delete Container `disk2` afterwards
   - expand the remaining Container disk1
3. Backup *Mac 2* with Time Machine and restore it after booting to Internet Recovery Mode to a completely erased and repartitioned `disk0`